# Definition of fractional ideal

Tags: modules, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, finitely-generated

I have a little problem with the definition of a fractional ideal. The definition I've been given is a set $f\subseteq Q=\text{Frac}(R)$ such that $\exists b\in R\backslash \{0\}$ such that $b.f\subseteq R$.

Apparently it's equivalent to $f$ being a finitely generated $R$-module. I don't understand why. I can't seem to find a reason for $f$ to be a group, or to be stable by multiplication by an element of $R$.

I saw at several places that  we require both statements in the definition of a fractional ideal. That is  $f$ must be a finitely generated $R$-module, and we require the existence of the $b$. Is it the case ? Is my definition incomplete ?  And if not why does it imply that it's a finitely generated $R$-module ?

Comment: [The wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal) looks clear enough. In short terms, you require both statements in the definition.

Comment: Yes it's clear but I thought that one or the other wasn't necessary. For example if we suppose it's a finitely generated $A$-module with generators $\frac{u_1}{v_1}, \dots ,\frac{u_r}{v_r}$, by taking $b=v_1\dots v_n$, we get $b.f \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the isomorphism $f\rightarrow b\cdot f,x\mapsto bx$. As $b\cdot f$ is an integral ideal, it is finitely generated as $R$-module (recall that a Dedekind domain is Noetherian), so $f$, which is isomorphic to $b\cdot f$, is clearly a finitely generated $R$-module.